# nano - include: command not found

Tags: nano

I am trying to edit my .nanorc file to include the syntax highlighting profiles located in /etc/share/nano/ folder.

When I have the first line as 'set tabsize 4', I get an error: 'set: Variable name must begin with a letter' when I source the .nanorc file but the include files are read correctly and I get the highlighting.

When omit the first line 'set tabsize 4', I get an error: 'include: command not found', when I source the .nanorc file.

What is going on? How do I properly correct this?

Using Red Hat, 3.10

example .nanorc file:

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
set autoindent
include /etc/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738930/edit) your question and include the entire `.nanorc` file, enclosed in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting. Also you should include the commands and error messages the same way. Knowing your OS version is furthermore also important. For example; here's a solution for `include` not found on Ubuntu from Ask Ubuntu SE site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006868/cannot-source-nanorc-correctly-command-include-not-found

Comment: Small remark: enclosing in brackets doesn't do code formatting; selecting and clicking on the brackets button on top of the editor does

Comment: hexdump -C your .nanorc to check for invisible characters

Comment: *"when I source the .nanorc file"* are you trying to `source` or `.` it into a shell? it's not a shell script

Comment: @steeldriver, good point. It is not a shell script and should not be treating it as one. There is no need to source it after editing it. Any changes will be loaded when launching nano itself.